# Construct the (one-step) transition matrix.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that a communications network transmits binary digits 0 or 1  where each digit is transmitted 10 times in succes- sion. During each transmission, the probability is 0.995 that the digit entered will be transmitted accurately. In other words, the probability is 0.005 that the digit being transmitted will be recorded with the opposite value at the end of the transmission. For each transmission after the first one, the digit entered for trans- mission is the one that was recorded at the end of the preceding transmission. If $X_0$ denotes the binary digit entering the system, $X_1$ the binary digit recorded after the first transmission, $X_2$ the bi- nary digit recorded after the second transmission, . . . , then {${X_n}$} is a Markov chain.

Comment: After you copy-paste the question, you also need to revise it and remove the "-" signs at the end of lines of the original text .

Comment: There is a MC to answer a question which is not asked. Supposing that it is around the probability of change after $k$ steps , what states did you selected  ?

Comment: So, what’s the question?